# requestAnimationFrame javascript alert increment jumps from 1 to 9 or 13

Tags: javascript, jquery, requestanimationframe

I've got this weird problem, I'm incrementing by 1, and yet, the increment that appears when the javascript window pops up, shows that I have incremented either by 9 or 13, the either comes from whether I am incrementing by 1 or -1 respectively. what is up with that?

This the function being called by the requestAnimationFrame

```
function stream1() {
  if (y > origin_y){
    var xOffset = -1;
  } else if (y == origin_y){
    var xOffset = 1;
  } else {
    var xOffset = 1;
  }

  var offset = $( "#widget1" ).offset();
  var x = offset.left; 
  var y = offset.top;
  console.log(' X - '+x+' Y - '+y);
  $( "#widget1" ).offset({ top: y-yOffset, left: xInitial+xOffset });
}
```

This is the animation frame

```
var globalID;
function repeatOften() {
  stream1();
  requestAnimationFrame(repeatOften);
}
```

It probably doesn't make sense that in the time for the alert to disappear and reappear, 9 iterations have been complete right? It's supposed to be 60 times a second supposedly and it has been like 1 second so shouldn't it be 60 and not 9 or 13? I don't know where these arbitrary numbers come from.

To summarize again, initially xInitial is located at 1114 px, then it goes to 1105 or 1103 and then 9 or 13 gaps subsequentially every time so why is that?

Comment: what alert are you talking about? I see no alert in your code.  and what is xInitial?  it is crticial for the output and you leave it out of your snippet?   what is globalID?  if it doesn't matter why put it in the snippet?    Your question could be asked much clearer and your code snippet could be much cleaner.

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you post an example on codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: the alert was like an echo, a way for me to see what the current position was, so I alert(xInitial) which is widget position left, this alerts 1114, then the next time around it alerts 1103, that's what I don't understand

Answer (score 1):

First, avoid expensive operation in frame callback. Like `$( "#widget1" ).offset()`. Mind that it is DOM operation, it can be slow and broke all timing. You can get DOM id and offset before animation starts and then remember just current offset left and top.

Second, if you want to be super precise, you can use handler urgument, which is timestamp and if you store animation start timestamp you can compute exact position regardless of real frame ratio.

Comment: and similar to second offset call to set it, it can faster use directly css with position relative/absolute and top, left properties

Comment: I position the widget slightly out of the frame, then using the top and left coordinate, and the arc "calculations" I move the widget along the arc, but as I said, the offset is not happening correctly